# How to make something true if xpath is visible on python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to make something like this work?

```
while mining_first_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[12]/button/div/span/svg'):
      mining_quest_in_progress = True

while mining_quest_done == True:

        mining_quest_done_not_collected_quest_click_2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[12]/button/div/span/svg")
        mining_quest_done_not_collected_quest_click_2.click()
        print("Hero is done")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you try to do.

Comment: you can't use `=` in `while` - maybe you means `for mining_first_button in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(...)` because `find_elements_xxx` gives list, not single element. OR maybe you need `if browser.find_elements_by_xpath(...):`

Comment: I'd most likely use while True: try: #checks if element is there and click except Exception as e: print(str(e)) break

Answer (score 0):

Some workaround like this should work:

```
mining_first_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[12]/button/div/span/svg')
if len(mining_first_button)>0:
      #... your code here ....
else:
    print("No such xpath exists")
```

You may use `try/except` too in lieu of `if/else`